# Aptana synchronising remote changes

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I have Aptana Studio 3 set up using the Deployment Wizard to sync changes in both directions from local/remote for my projects. This works fine for syncing local changes to the remote site; my changes get FTP'd up automatically.

It doesn't seem to be working out when a file has changed remotely - there have been several situations where I've opened a file that has been modified by someone else since I last downloaded it, and the remote changes have not been downloaded to my local copy.

I've been manually synchronising directories before starting to work on them but this is a bit of an annoying workaround. Is it possible for Aptana to automatically check for remote changes, and sync my local copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug report which pretty much answers my own question: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2811

Unfortunately it doesn't look like this is going to be fixed any time soon. It's a pretty essential feature IMO, especially for those working in teams.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using Git for moving files around (plus the whole version saving feature).

If you make a change on your local development system, simply

```
$  git add .
$  git commit -m "made a change"
$  git push origin
```

And then pull it down on your deployment server.

```
$  git pull
```

All done.

If you make a change on your deployment server, simply commit that change on the deployment server, and subsequently pull that change down to your development machine.  There isn't really that much of a need for FTP anymore, although it does come in handy for moving untracked binary files.

http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1